# jparepository error creating entitymanagerfactory

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jpa

now i'm trying to config jpa data with spring mvc. But i'm getting exception when trying execute on tomcat server.

I'm using tomcat 7.0.56
**and here is the exception:**

> Mar 10, 2016 10:11:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
>   SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
>       at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:82)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.pushClassTransformer(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:124)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:234)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>       ... 21 more

and here is my config file so far

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.broxigar.controller"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/adventrip" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- Set JPA properties -->
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- Set base package of your entities -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.broxigar.models" />
    <!-- Set share cache mode -->
    <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" />
    <!-- Set validation mode -->
    <property name="validationMode" value="NONE" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- Configure Spring Data JPA and set the base package of the repository 
    interfaces -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.broxigar.repositories" />
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.broxigar</groupId>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>broxigar</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <finalName>rest</finalName>
</build>
```

can anyone guide me to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception says: `"Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation"`

If you *don't need* time weaving (that most likely) just remove `loadTimeWeaver` property from declaration of entity manager in your XML configuration.

In this case you also have to remove from props list of `jpaProperties` property, named `hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer` or set its value to false.

---

But, if you *need* time weaving lets see [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw):

> ...Further, in certain environments, this support enables load-time
>   weaving without making any modifications to the application server’s
>   launch script that will be needed to add
>   -javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver.jar or (as we describe later in this section)
>   -javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument-{version}.jar (previously named spring-agent.jar).

So, try to add JVM parameter:

```
-javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

Where `path/to/` more likely would to point to your local Maven repository. For set JVM parameter with Maven, you can use `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable. In Windows it will look like:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-javaagent:"path/to/org.springframework.instrument-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar" %MAVEN_OPTS%
```

Comment: i still got same error after i added those argument to vm arguments in eclipse. The arguments look like this: '-javaagent:C:\Users\Kevin\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.2.0.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar -Dcatalina.base="E:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="C:\xampp\tomcat" -Dwtp.deploy="E:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\xampp\tomcat\endorsed"' what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Let's try to make path in javaagent quoted.

Comment: still no use, if i just delete property InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver it gives error that said Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified

Comment: @StillNewbie because you didn't remove `hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer` property. Sorry, I had to note it from start. I updated my answer according to this.

Comment: Would like to add for anyone else who comes across this error. Remove 
<context:load-time-weaver/>
If it is also in your XML if you do not need time weaving.